# Square brackets in parameter name

Tags: apiary.io, apiblueprint

I was wondering if it's possible to include square brackets in the parameter name, which is how Rails groups parameters. For example:

```
    + Parameters
        + person[age] (string) ... Person's age
```

Right now if I include the square bracket, the parameter doesn't get rendered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically square brackets are not allowed in an URI except the `Internet Protocol Literal Address`

RFC3513:

> A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6 [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal within square brackets ("[" and "]"). This is the only place where square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax.

Which implies the square bracket SHOULD NOT be used (unescaped) in a parameter name.

A solution for now would be to escape the brackets manually.

In the future the API Blueprint may automatically escape unsafe characters for you. Refer to:

- [Report square brackets in URI templates](https://github.com/apiaryio/snowcrash/issues/58)
- [Escape Unsafe Characters in URI Templates](https://github.com/apiaryio/snowcrash/issues/61)