# Not able to get query paramter value using android.net.Uri#getQueryParameter

Tags: java, android, uri, query-string

I'm trying to parse query parameters from a URL string using [Uri.getQueryParameter(String key)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#getQueryParameter(java.lang.String)) but that method returns `null` for the passed-in key. That URL that I'm using is `/endpoint/path?query1=foo&page[size]=1`. I'm able to successfully get the value for `query1` parameter but not for `page[size]`(the method returns `null` for this key). My code looks like:

```
import android.net.Uri

val uri = Uri.parse("/endpoint/path?query1=foo&page[size]=1")
val queryParameterNames = uri.getQueryParameterNames()

println(queryParameterNames) // prints ["query1", "page[size]"]

val map = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
queryParameterNames.forEach { name ->
    map[name] = uri.getQueryParameter(name) ?: ""
}

println(map) // prints {query1=foo, page[size]=}
```

As seen in the output of the last line, the value of `page[size]` is empty. I suspect it has something to do with `[`, `]` characters in the query parameter name for `page[size]`, with them being url encoded while looking for the value but I'm not sure why this is actually failing. So, I have a couple of questions here:

1. Why is it successful in finding the names for the query parameters but fails when finding their corresponding values?
2. How can I get the value of `page[size]` parameter from the url string in Android?

Comment: Are you sure that is a valid URL? https://stackoverflow.com/q/11490326/115145 https://stackoverflow.com/a/20422756/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare As per the links that you provided, it seems like it is not. That query parameter should be encoded in the URL. If you can convert your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as an accepted answer and close this question. Thank you for finding and providing the supporting information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Android's `Uri` implementation is getting confused over those square brackets, as [those appear to be invalid URL syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490326/is-array-syntax-using-square-brackets-in-url-query-strings-valid).

If you control the Web service, you might reconsider the use of square brackets, as they may cause problems with other clients. Otherwise, you may need to play some icky regex games to replace those square brackets with escaped equivalents or otherwise find ways to sanitize the URL before fully parsing it with `Uri`.